# Cannot find type definition file for 'docs'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this error showing in VSC when in the `tsconfig.json` file

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'docs'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'docs'
```

I don't have any dependencies with the name 'docs' so I am very confused. I have tried deleting my node_modules folder, but it didn't work.

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "noEmit": false,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types/"],
    }
}
```

My Dependancies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.6.0",
    "@types/": "typegoose/typegoose",
    "@types/amqplib": "^0.5.17",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/coinbase-commerce-node": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.10.5",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.1",
    "amqplib": "^0.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "coinbase-commerce-node": "^1.0.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.7"
  }
```

Comment: Can you add more details from the error stack?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Turned nout to be a silly issue, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that for some reason I had `@types/` in the dependancies, I'm guessing this was from a malformed `yarn add` command.